# How can I stop a small portion of particles from jumping around in render animation?

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I'm currently rendering [this shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18rFNkaafBqcKTXl0Cb1cuKVfE0XqwklO/view?usp=sharing) (among others) and some of the leaves in the particle system jump around at specific frames. It doesn't appear to be random though.

The modifier stack has A displace modifier, an armature, and three particle systems (the problem occurs on the third one)

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bHertuIfJllfIJPJsxOuyHYMpstgbNDw/view?usp=sharing) are the settings for the particle system. The issue doesn't occur in the viewport, which makes it a little harder to approach.

I have narrowed my search down to turning off my density vertex group, which reduces the amount of wobbling a bit, but not completely.

Please let me know how I can explain this better and I hope I can get some help because I've been struggling with this for a few days now. Thanks!

Comment: probably because the animation makes the hair move? I don't know if there's a way to avoid that, except make instances real

Comment: the geometry doesn't look like its making the same jump that would cause the hair root to jump as well. Any other thoughts?